# Arduino and External Peripherals

Tags: arduino

I am a CS guy getting started with Arduino. This is probably  a very basic electronics question but from going over the arduino tutorials everything is connected to the arduino with a resistor.

Well since i am following the tutorials i know what type of resistor i should use but what i do not know is why i should use one? and What type of resistor to pick i am to do something which is not covered in a tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The resistor simply serves to limit the current into or out of a pin in case something goes awry.  If your AVR decides to output high on a pin that something else wants low (or vice-versa), large, damaging currents can occur if not limited by some resistance.  The current limit for AVRs is about 20 milliamps, and given that the voltages are usually 5V, something larger than 250 ohms "would work".

To give a margin of safety, 1-10k is a great choice; for digital signals it seldom matters unless you're into very high-speed applications (beyond the AVRs capability anyways).  For analog inputs, a similar resistor would also be advisable, as the amount of current the ADC takes to sample is negligible when your resistor is in the few kilo-ohm range.

Answer (score 6):

The underlying principle that you want to learn is [Ohm's Law](http://www.kpsec.freeuk.com/ohmslaw.htm), which describes the relationship between voltage, resistance, and current in a circuit.

Answer (score 5):

Resistors are used to

1. limit current,
2. [devide voltage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)
3. protect against over voltage
4. pull-up, pull down
5. current to voltage conversion
6. etc ...

1) limit output current, the absolute max current per IO is 40mA, a typical LED works on ±2V 20mA. 
the resistance value can by calculated by (5V - 2V)/(0.02A)=150Ω usually a 220Ω resistor is used, because: it consumes less power, there doesn't flow 20 milliamps, and there is no notable difference in emitted light.

2) if you have a analog voltage that variates between 0 and 10 Volts, you 'll need a voltage divider of 1/2. pick by example z2 10k and calculate z1 by 10k*(Vin,max/5V -1). take a value of resistance higher than the original calculated. and recalculate the new Vout. 

3) place a resistor of 10k in series between the analog input of the arduino and the 'to measure voltage' 

3) if you have to measure a analog current, you place a resistor to ground and the analog input, calculate the resistor by Z=5V/amps.

4) if you connect a button to the arduino, you 'll need to place a pull up or a pull down resistor. if you 're not using a resistor, the input is floating and can take any value (high or low). or you can enable the internal weak pull up. by pinMode(xx,INPUT); digitalWrite(xx,HIGH);. and disabeling by digitalWrite(xx,LOW); by default the pull-up is disabled.